Unable to initialize controller_manager and spawn controllers in ROS 2 Humble using ros2_control
I am currently facing an issue with initializing the controller_manager and spawning controllers for my robot in ROS 2 Humble. I have set up my robot's URDF and YAML configuration files, but I am encountering errors when trying to launch my setup. Below are the details of my setup and the error logs.
Setup Details:
ROS 2 Distro: Humble
Robot Description: URDF file (cart.urdf)
Controller Manager Configuration: YAML file (controller_manager.yaml)
Launch File: cart_launch.py
controller_manager.yaml
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    velocity_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
      joints:
        - slider_to_cart
      command_interfaces:
        - velocity
      state_interfaces:
        - position
        - velocity

    effort_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController
      joints:
        - slider_to_cart

    position_controller:
      type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
      joints:
        - slider_to_cart

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    imu_sensor_broadcaster:
      type: imu_sensor_broadcaster/IMUSensorBroadcaster

imu_sensor_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    sensor_name: cart_imu_sensor
    frame_id: imu


cart_launch.py
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription, OpaqueFunction
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import os

def launch_setup(context, *args, **kwargs):
    # Get the package directory
    cartbon_one_dir = get_package_share_directory('cartbon_one')

    # Launch configuration variables
    model = LaunchConfiguration('model').perform(context)
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time').perform(context)
    control_mode = LaunchConfiguration('control_mode').perform(context)

    # Determine which controller to use based on the control mode
    controller_type = {
        'velocity': 'velocity_controller',
        'effort': 'effort_controller',
        'position': 'position_controller'
    }

    # Define the path to the controller manager YAML file
    controller_manager_yaml = os.path.join(cartbon_one_dir, 'config', 'controller_manager.yaml')

    return [
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(cartbon_one_dir, 'launch', 'rsp.launch.py')]),
            launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}.items()
        ),
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
            output='screen'
        ),
        Node(
            package='gazebo_ros',
            executable='spawn_entity.py',
            arguments=['-entity', 'cart', '-file', model],
            output='screen'
        ),
        Node(
            package='controller_manager',
            executable='ros2_control_node',
            parameters=[controller_manager_yaml],
            output='screen'
        ),
        Node(
            package='controller_manager',
            executable='spawner',
            arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster'],
            output='screen'
        ),
        Node(
            package='controller_manager',
            executable='spawner',
            arguments=[controller_type[control_mode]],
            output='screen'
        )
    ]

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='model',
            default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('cartbon_one'), 'description', 'cart.urdf'),
            description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='control_mode',
            default_value='velocity',
            description='Control mode: velocity, effort, or position'
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='use_sim_time',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use simulation time if true'
        ),
        OpaqueFunction(function=launch_setup)
    ])


Error Log
When I run the launch file with the command ros2 launch cartbon_one cart_launch.py control_mode:=velocity, I get the following error:
[gazebo-2] [Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1719725894.208481140] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1719725894.223943988] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1719725896.233809796] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1719725896.235454352] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1719725898.251507196] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1719725898.256170417] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1719725900.264046182] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1719725900.266237863] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1719725902.280914592] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1719725902.287807060] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 9755, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner velocity_controller --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 9752, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].


It seems that the controller_manager is not being initialized properly, and therefore the spawners are unable to access it. I have confirmed that the paths to the URDF and YAML files are correct.
I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!


Looks like controller_manager not able to spawn.
Try the following

Get URDF via Xacro file


robot_description_content = Command(
    [
        PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
        " ",
        PathJoinSubstitution(
            [FindPackageShare("ros2_control_demo_example_2"), "urdf", "diffbot.urdf.xacro"]
        ),
        " ",
        "use_mock_hardware:=",
        "false",
    ]
)
robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}



Pass the robot_description info via remapping


    Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='ros2_control_node',
        parameters=[controller_manager_yaml],
        output='screen', 
        remappings=[
             ("~/robot_description", "/robot_description"),
        ],
    ),



keep in mind: There is no need for ros2_control_node if using gazebo_ros2_control


It seems that the controller_manager is not being initialized
properly, and therefore the spawners are unable to access it.

This is exactly the case.
First, try the examples of gazebo_ros2_control_demos. Do they launch? If no, there is probably a problem with rosdep as suggested in the already linked answer.
If yes, compare your setup with the demos. E.g., gazebo is launched with
gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch'), '/gazebo.launch.py']),
             )

in the demos instead of executing the gazebo process manually.

Try checking this answer I posted to a similar issue.
Hope it works out for you.
Cheers!
